# What is the NodeJS mongoDB client equivalent to Mongoose populate?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to switch over from use Mongoose to using the MongoDB driver for JavaScript.  Inside some of my documents I have relationships with others.  I was wondering about how to "populate" these.  With Mongoose I can do something like:

```
Collections.find().populate("field")
```

I am wondering how would I do the equivalent with the MongoDB driver.  Is there some function for doing that?  Or, ideally, maybe some way to do it within the aggregation pipeline?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Look like what you need is https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I needed.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. You can do it.

You can create a function:

```
exports.joinRetailCollection = (collectionName, collectionJoinName, foreignFieldName, asFieldName) =>  state.db.collection(collectionName).aggregate([
  { 
    $lookup: 
    {
      from: collectionName,
      localField:  collectionJoinName,
      foreignField: foreignFieldName,
      as: asFieldName
    }
}
]);

from: 'user',
localField: 'products',
foreignField: 'sku',
as: 'inventory'
```

and import it in

```
enter code here
```

const {db} = require('../route');

and create a variable

const userLink = db.joinRetailCollection('user', .....) //the arguments of the function.

Add this to your mongo-connector.js file

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

const state = {
  db: null,
}

exports.connect = async (url, done) => {
  if (state.db) return done()
  MongoClient.connect(url, { 
    connectTimeoutMS: 200,
    retryWrites: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true, 
    useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, client) => {
    if (err) return done(err)
    state.db = client.db('wp_test')
    done()
  })
}`

exports.getCollection = (collectionName) => state.db.collection(collectionName);
```

and then the fnctions
you also add one for collection only in the same file

Hope this will be useful for you.

Kind regards

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I think I generally understand the concept of what you are explaining here. However, it isn't completely clear. If you could double check your answer and make it more clear/general, then I would be glad to accept it as an answer.

Comment: Hey sure. I am going to write you step by step.  In my case I am using Apollo, but configuration is the same. So I have this folder structure. src --> (db, constants, controllers, graphql, utils, services, maybe models. In the db folder I have another folder name connector, inside it, I created a mongo-connector.js in which I configure mongodb. By the code I attached you in other comment or you can also read it in the first answer. Then I imported to the index.js which is the root file. With apollo is in the context part with is available in the whole app. But here with the code I leave you.

Comment: Follow the link to see the example code. In this case is apollo-server. But you can have access to the DB in the same way I did it. Hope you it works for you. Anyway, you can answer again if it wasn´t the case. Kind regards.  https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-mountain-7m12t

Comment: how would you populate a field in objects that are in array : `{list:[{refField:ObjectId, /*other fields */}, ...more objects ]}` ? im in need for a equivalent like that.