# How to return array of references from mongodb?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, mongodb

I've got json like below, stored in mongodb:

```
{
  createdAt: 1641840199,
  name: 'hello'
  projects: [ new ObjectId("61dc99b2fdfbd72f33d4d699") ]
}
```

in `projects` array i've got an reference to the documents with project. And now i've got a question, how to return an array of this objects (full objects, not only it reference id).

PS. I'm using `mongodb` library, i do not like `moongose`.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you tried [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#-lookup--aggregation-)?

Comment: @Joe, No, can you show an example?

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61094443/what-is-the-nodejs-mongodb-client-equivalent-to-mongoose-populate

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```
db.NAME.findOne({ projects: ObjectId("61dc99b2fdfbd72f33d4d699") });
```